# Continuous postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I can't figure out why my page keeps on refreshing, then I put a breakpoint on my Page_Load on aspx page. It keeps on refreshing and loading the Page_Load without me doing anything.

I have some textboxes that has AutoPostBack="True" for TextChange event. Do you guys think that is the problem? Do you guys have any idea why it keeps on doing POST?

Thank you, guys.

These are some of the code.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VesselSchedule.aspx.cs" Inherits="VesselHeader.VesselSchedule" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>


<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnVesselCode">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Vessel Code</label>                  
  <div class="col-sm-4">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtVesselCode" runat="server" class="form-control pull-left" placeholder="Vessel Code" onkeypress="return EnterEvent(event)" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtVesselCode_TextChanged" />
      <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="blue" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Button ID="btnVesselCode" runat="server" Text="Button" visible="false" OnClick="btnVesselCode_Click"/>
   </div>
 </asp:Panel>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group date">
         <div class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
         </div>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtPublishedETADate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="form-control" OnTextChanged="txtPublishedETADate_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"/>
     </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: By chance, do you have an UpdatePanel on your page? Other relevant controls other than the mentioned text boxes? Show some code :)

Comment: @jcruz I don't have an updatepanel. Okay, I will show some of the code :)

Comment: can you also add your pageload event code

Comment: It's empty @Sujit.Warrier

Comment: any anchor tags with href="#" in your page ?

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of PostBack will fire the Page_Load event.
To not run the entire code in Page_Load on each post back you need to wrap your code inside a check. A simple if condition will do it for you.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
//code to execute on fresh page load only.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my main problem is it keeps on doing PostBack even if I'm not doing or clicking anything. Just like in the picture that I posted, almost every 0.2milliseconds.

Comment: Not sure what would cause those postbacks. Is your page reloading or they are async post calls?